# Is it okay to use Javascript class objects in Vuex state?

Tags: vuex

Lets say I have a simple Vuex state to hold a recipe:

```
const state = {
    recipe: {
        id: '',
        name: "",
        ingredients : [],
    }
};
```

Is it a good practice to instead create a recipe class holding the same data, and then in the state declare it as an instance of the class?

```
const state = {
    recipe: new Recipe()
};
```

If the recipe class has methods, should those methods be proxied via getters/mutations on the vuex store, or is it okay to call the methods directly?

Comment: I have the same question. I found the following post in the Vue forum and hope it helps: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143/2

Answer (score 2):

While I can not give an authoritative answer, I would say yes, you *should* use classes in the state. I consider this good practice in line with the [Separation of Concern design principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). However, you should not have methods on those classes to call directly.

## tl;dr;

- use classes as DTOs or models
- keep state clean of methods, but you might add some "locally calculated state" if needed.
- mutate data as much as you need in the mutations, even mutating some "locally calculated state" from above, if needed.
- if needed, pick specific data with specific getters, possibly having many getters for the same underlying data
- if needed, implement separate code outside the state, getters and mutations instead of methods directly in those.

## Example

In my application, using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) and [typescript](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html), I have written a "api-model" that represents the various parts of my API responses and requests and some as `unitTree.ts` helper class code that is responsible for the handling of the `enterpriseUnitsTree` part of the state, which is a local subset of the `caseFullData`.

Here's how I do it in the state.ts (simplified):

```
import { ICaseFullDataViewModel, CaseFullDataViewModel, CaseApprovalDto, ICaseApprovalDto } from '@/api-model';
import { IEnterpriseUnitDataObjectTree } from '../code/unitTree';

export interface IEntryState {
    caseValidationMessages: string[];
    caseFullData: ICaseFullDataViewModel;
    enterpriseUnitsTree: Array<IEnterpriseUnitDataObjectTree>;
    caseApproval: ICaseApprovalDto;
}

export const state: IEntryState = {
    caseValidationMessages: null,
    caseFullData: new CaseFullDataViewModel(),
    enterpriseUnitsTree: null,
    caseApproval: new CaseApprovalDto()
};
```

As for getting data, I would recommend having a complete set of getters for each aspect you need. It keeps the state clean as really to be only a state, not a business/use case in itself. See below some getters for parts of the above data. For example, I am using external code in `unitTree.ts` to extract a specific item of `enterpriseUnitsTree` from the store.

Here's my code in getters.ts (simplified):

```
import { IRootState } from '@/store';
import { GetterTree } from 'vuex';
import { unitTree } from '../code/unitTree';
import { IEntryState } from './state';

export const CASE_ID = 'caseId';
export const CASE_FULL_DATA = 'caseFullData';
export const UNITS_SORTED_AS_TREE = 'unitsSortedAsTree';
export const FIRST_UNIT = 'firstUnit';


export const getters: GetterTree<IEntryState, IRootState> = {
    [CASE_ID]: state => state.caseFullData?.caseId,  
    [CASE_FULL_DATA]: state => state.caseFullData,
    [UNITS_SORTED_AS_TREE]: state => {
        return state.enterpriseUnitsTree;
    },
    [FIRST_UNIT]: state => () => {        
        const indexMap = unitTree.getIndexMap(state.enterpriseUnitsTree);
        const firstUnitIdentifier = indexMap.get(0);        
        return firstUnitIdentifier;
    }
    //.... 
};
```

In the `mutations.ts`, I do mutate the the `enterpriseUnitsTree`, as needed, when receiving a commit the the respective data:

Here's my code in mutations.ts (simplified):

```
import { MutationTree } from 'vuex';
import {
    ICaseFullDataViewModel    
} from '@/api-viewmodel';
import { IEntryState } from './state';
import { unitTree } from '../code/unitTree';

export const MAPCASEFULLDATA = 'mapCaseFullData';
//....

export const mutations: MutationTree<IEntryState> = {
    [MAPCASEFULLDATA](state, value: ICaseFullDataViewModel) {
        state.caseFullData = value;
        //... some sorting and tree building using code from unitTree
        state.enterpriseUnitsTree = sortedEnterpriseUnits;
    },
    //.......
};
```